# Asp.net, Syntax highlight code from file with google prettify

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-code-prettify, asp-literal

In my page I will get the ID from link parameters, with that ID I will search the database for the file path, after reading the file and storing its contents I want to put its contents inside my `<pre>` tag... So I will have a literal in which the text for it will be:

```
Code.Text = "<pre>" + File Contents in string + "</pre>";
```

My question is how will I insert the contents there if I need to read the file line by line into an string array, unless I read it all into one string, **BUT** that will make the text look like one huge line in the page.

Also, is it going to conflict with `literal` syntax(?) definitions, since for quotes we have to do `\"` instead of `"` ...?

Comment: What have you tried? Can we see your code? And \" isn't 'literal syntax', it's used to escape characters in constants *only*, not in variable values. Meaning: `var s = "\""; MessageBox.Show(s);` will show a message box with just a double quote `"`

Comment: @wgraham I know it isn't literal syntax and thanks for correcting me anyways, wouldn't figure out the term any time soon :b ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with literal control, you use the `StringBiulder` And `Append` properties becouse It let you put any HTML code from code behind.
Something like:

```
    //Declare your String Builder
    private StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
```

And also you could have any proccess when you read the file, and split it by any char like \n

```
        string readFile = //Any Method that you read you file string.
        string[] tokens = readFile.Split('\n');
        stb.Append("<pre>");

        foreach (string s in tokens)
        {
            stb.Append( s + "<\br>");
        }
        stb.Append("</pre>");
```

finally you attach the Stringbuilder value to you Literal

```
YourLiteral.Text = stb.ToString();
```

I hope that help, and you won't have the value in one line. And remember the carring return need be in the string file to the split works.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, it worked 5 stars, the `<\br>` wasn't needed after all :b worked fine with string builder.